# Count amount of items with the same value in the table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
postID postTitle   postDesc          postCont          postDate            postUser
     2 titleUpdate <p>DescUpdate</p> <p>ContUpdate</p> 2014-10-27 16:31:24 admin
```

I want to get the amount of items with the postUser as admin
Which in this case is 1.
Could someone help me with this?

EDIT:
Sorry, i meant $_SESSION['login'] instead of admin.
So search where postUser is $_SESSION['login']

EDIT2:
When i use this: SELECT count(*) FROM yourtable WHERE postUser = 'admin'
I am getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'admin' (T_STRING) in D:\xampp\htdocs\AAWebsite\blog\index.php on line 93

My line 93: $getamount = $db->query('SELECT count(*) FROM blog_posts WHERE postUser = 'admin'');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:-

```
SELECT count(*) FROM yourtable WHERE postUser = 'admin'
```

Here yourtable is the name of the database table.

Comment: Getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'admin' (T_STRING) in D:\xampp\htdocs\AAWebsite\blog\index.php on line 93

Line 93:      
$getamount = $db->query('SELECT count(*) FROM blog_posts WHERE postUser = 'admin'');

Comment: The single quotes are not closed properly. Use double quotes and single quotes properly on the statement. Use the following:- $getamount = $db->query("SELECT count(*) FROM blog_posts WHERE postUser = 'admin'");

Comment: If I echo it this error occurs:
Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in D:\xampp\htdocs\AAWebsite\blog\index.php on line 105

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tableName
WHERE postUser = 'admin'
```

where `tableName` is the name of that database table.

Comment: $getamount = $db->query('SELECT count(*) FROM tableName WHERE postUser = $_SESSION['login']');

This isn't working

Comment: Change the outer quotes from single to double.

Comment: isnt working. It gives me an error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in ....